# WPF with MVVM: can't write/read data in/from textboxes in different pages

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

So I've been making this program for my end project. and I'm using pages in a tab control to us in my WPF. in these pages, the user fills in all the data in the pages and then press a button, that will save the data and send it to the server. Or they can load in the data from the server, and the data should appear in the textboxes in the MVVM. But it doesn't, neither does it read any data from the textboxes. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Under here are some bits of my code (it has 59 items, so I just show a few). And only the insert from the server. since if this is fixed, the save/update would also be fixed easily I think. Thank you in advance

Window.xaml.cs -

```cs
public void DataInlezen(string Json)
{
    DataGebruiker viewmodel = new DataGebruiker();
    var Djson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonCS>(Json);

    foreach (var AlgeInf in Djson.algemeneInformatie)
    {
        viewmodel.Achternaam = AlgeInf.Achternaam;
        viewmodel.Voornaam = AlgeInf.Voornaam;
        viewmodel.Straat = AlgeInf.Straat;
        viewmodel.Huisnummer = AlgeInf.Huisnummer;
        viewmodel.Postcode = AlgeInf.Postcode;
        viewmodel.Stad = AlgeInf.Stad;
        viewmodel.Email = AlgeInf.Email;
        viewmodel.GSM = AlgeInf.GSM;
        viewmodel.Beroep = AlgeInf.Beroep;
        viewmodel.Leeftijd = AlgeInf.Leeftijd;
        viewmodel.Geslacht = AlgeInf.Geslacht;
    }
```

Model -

```cs
public class DataGebruiker : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _Achternaam;
    public string Achternaam
    {
        get
        {
            return _Achternaam;
        }
        set
        {
            _Achternaam = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Achternaam");
        }
    }
    private string _Voornaam;
    public string Voornaam
    {
        get
        {
            return _Voornaam;
        }
        set
        {
            _Voornaam = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Voornaam");
        }
    }

//more stuff
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
```

ViewModel -

```cs
internal class DataGebruikerViewModel
{
    private readonly DataGebruiker _DataGebruiker;
    public DataGebruikerViewModel()
    {
        _DataGebruiker = new DataGebruiker();
    }        

    public DataGebruiker DataGebruiker
    {
        get
        {
            return _DataGebruiker;
        }
    }
```

XAML -

```xml
<Page.DataContext>
        <local:DataGebruikerViewModel/>
</Page.DataContext>
<!--some layout stuff-->

<TextBox Name="TextBoxAchternaam" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding DataGebruiker.Achternaam}" FontSize="24" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="6" />
<TextBox Name="TextBoxVoornaam" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding DataGebruiker.Voornaam}" FontSize="24" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="6" />

<Button Name="ButtonOpzoeken" Grid.Column="1" Content="Opzoeken" Grid.Row="8" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  FontSize="24" Click="ButtonOpzoeken_Click"/> //button to save
```

Comment: A few tips... the `INotifyPropertyChanged` should be on the view model not the model.  Yes there will be some pass through properties to the model but that is normal in MVVM... Then instead of using the `button.Click` event use `<Button Command="{Binding OpzoekenCommand}"` and have an `ICommand OpzoekenCommand` property in the view model.  Also the text box binding should have `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` if you want to have the property in the view model update as the user types.

Comment: implementing INPC on models are acceptable, it's not a wpf interface, it's part of System.ComponentModel.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2010/july/design-patterns-problems-and-solutions-with-model-view-viewmodel

Comment: @chancea I did all this and this actually seem to work well, the model gets updated when the View gets updated. so the propertychnage is now in the Viewmodel. I also used the Icommand and this also works amazingly well, but the only problem I'm now stuck with is that the data from the server makes it into the model, but the viewmodel and the view don't react on the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is because the instance of that DataGebruiker which is binded in the view is different than the one instantiated by DataInlezen method.

Comment: I fixed that, it only gets instantiated only once, in the ViewModel. and when sending data, I send it via that, but the ViewModel neither the view wants to update

Comment: can you also post the new updated code? from what I see in the first post,  the DataInlezen method is creating a new instance of DataGebruiker while the viewmodel also has another instance of DataGebruiker

Comment: Yeah, I fixed that problem, and I even fixed the problem in general, all I needed to do when I read the data and send it to the model from the ViewModel, is to call the `OnPropertyChanged`. this solved my problem. Both the tips from @chancea and your helped me. Thank you very much